# Applying Title Case (aka Proper Case) as a find & replace using regex in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, title-case

I am trying to apply Title Case (aka Proper Case) to multiple items in Notepad++ by using Regex.

The expression i'm finding is: 
`(?<=column caption=')(.*?)(?=')`

I just want to capitalise the start of each word.

```
e.g. this is a test = This Is A Test
e.g.2. This is a test = This Is A Test
e.g.3. this Is a Test = This Is A Test
etc.
```

If I use:
`\u\1` as replace, I am able to turn it into sentence case (i.e. This is a test). But what is the expression slash how do I turn all these finds into Title Case (or Proper Case)?

Thanks

Comment: Try `(?:\G(?!^)|column caption=')[^\w']*\K(\w+)` and replace with `\u$1`.

Comment: Or `(?:\G(?!^)|column caption=')[^\w']*\K(\w)(\w*)` and replace with `\U$1\L$2`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
(^[^\s]|\s+[^\s])
```

With:

```
\U$1
```

[image]